Select at random a rectangle from a $100\times100$ grid. What is the probability of selecting a square whose side length is greater than $50$?

Select at random a rectangle from a $100\times100$ grid such that the sides of the rectangle coincide with the edges of the grid. What is the probability of selecting a square whose side length is greater than $50$?

This problem is from a material I found online that doesn't come with a key, so I'm looking for some feedback on my solution. Thank you very much!

A rectangle is identified by two pairs of parallel lines on the grid. There are two orientations, each with $101$ lines. $\implies$ The number of rectangles is ${\dbinom{101}{2}}^2.$
Divide one side of the grid into three ordered segments whose lengths are $x, y + 51,$ and $z,$ respectively, with $x, y, z \geq 0.$ The segment $y + 51$ represents the image of a square whose side length is greater than $50$ on this side of the grid.
We have $x + (y + 51) + z = 100.$
If $y = 0, x + z = 49 \implies$ The number of squares whose side length is $51$ is ${\dbinom{50}{1}}^2 = 50^2$
$y = 1, x + z = 48 \implies$ The number of squares whose side length is $52$ is ${\dbinom{49}{1}}^2 = 49^2$
...
$ y =49, x + z = 0 \implies$ The number of squares whose side length is $100$ is $\dbinom{1}{1} = 1^2.$
Thus, the probability of selecting a square whose side length is greater than $50$ is $$P = \dfrac{\sum_{x=1}^{50} x^2}{{\dbinom{101}{2}}^2} = \dfrac{17}{10100}$$


The answer depends on the way to choose the rectangle. The way you proposed is not unique. The simplest one is to choose two points on the grid.

@user: there are ${\dbinom{101}{2}}^2$ rectangles. I assume the OP is assigning an equal probability to each of these.

@user Hi, thank you! The problem requires that the sides of the rectangle coincide with the edges of the grid, so I imagined we could only select the lines from the grid to make the rectangle? Please let me know what you think!

@TonyK Yes, given my experience with similar problems I've been practicing, I believe this problem assumes that each rectangle has an equal chance to be selected.

@ten_to_tenth You can also choose two points on intersection of grids and draw a vertical and horizontal lines. They will form a rectangle.

@TonyK This holds only if the degenerate rectangles are not allowed.

@user: "A rectangle is identified by two pairs of parallel lines..." And a pair of parallel lines means exactly two, not just one. I believe the OP's question is unambiguous.

@TonyK "A rectangle is identified by two pairs of parallel lines..." is not a part of the cited question. It is a part of the tried solution.

@TonyK If the question was "Select at random two distinct horizontal and two distinct vertical lines" I would agree that the question is unambiguous.

Maybe a simpler way to compute the number of ways you can place a square of size $n \times n$ is to count the number of placements of its upper left corner.

@JeanMarie Hi, thank you very much! I definitely must have overthought it after I failed to use stars and bars for some other problems where it's supposed to be used.
